# Scheme: mutating local variable in different environments mutates the same object

Tags: scheme, mutability, cons

Consider these two similar procedures:

```
(define (append-internal-cons obj)
  (let ((local-var (cons 1 '()) ))
    (append! local-var (list obj))
    local-var))

(define (append-internal-no-cons obj)
  (let ((local-var '(1) ))
    (append! local-var (list obj))
    local-var))
```

Given these two helper procedures:

```
(define (append! x y)
  (set-cdr! (last-pair x) y)
            x)
(define (last-pair ls)
  (if (null? (cdr ls))
             ls
             (last-pair (cdr ls))))
```

Calling the first one three times yields expected results: a list containing `1` and whatever `obj` we passed in.

```
(append-internal-cons 2) ;; (1 2)
(append-internal-cons 3) ;; (1 3)
(append-internal-cons 4) ;; (1 4)
```

I would expect calling the second version three times to yield the same results, but it doesn't.

```
(append-internal-no-cons 2) ;; (1 2)
(append-internal-no-cons 3) ;; (1 2 3)
(append-internal-no-cons 4) ;; (1 2 3 4)
```

Shouldn't the behavior of the two procedures be the same?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe mutating quoted literals is undefined behavior in the Scheme standard. Therefore, it is valid for an implementation to exhibit this behavior, but not all implementations will behave the same.

Comment: Mutating literals are not allowed in the Scheme standard. A scheme implementation is free to use one object for all occurrences of `'(1)` so this violation might even change other places. Most implementations don't signal am error since it's not required so you get unexpected behavior from a non scheme program (code that violates the report is not Scheme code)